# VirtualBox supR3HardenedMainInitRuntime! error

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-16.04

I get this error every time i try to launch VBox, after some researches i found that it maybe because installing vbox.deb placed in other folder not in  /opt. (i tried many other solution like reinstalling ...).
could any one propose other solution to me and/or explain to me how do i make my deb install in /opt folder thank you.

```
VBoxSDL: Error -610 in supR3HardenedMainInitRuntime!
VBoxSDL: dlopen("/usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxRT.so",) failed: <NULL>

VBoxSDL: Tip! It may help to reinstall VirtualBox.

VirtualBox: Error -610 in supR3HardenedMainInitRuntime!
VirtualBox: dlopen("/usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxRT.so",) failed: <NULL>

VirtualBox: Tip! It may help to reinstall VirtualBox.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At first,try

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall virtualbox
```

It may not be helpful,then this may give a hand:
[enter link description here](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/13670)

And in the end,you can try to reboot the machine.Is it is not work,then i have no idea.i hope one of them is able to solve you problem.

Comment: Only the apt install command is necessary from my experience. Otherwise you're just pulling a newer version of virtualbox and reinstalling that.

Answer (score 7):

Like described at https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/16759.
This fixed my problem (virtualbox 5.1.26r117224, kernel 4.10.0-33)

```
sudo chown root:root /usr 
sudo chown root:root /usr/lib 
sudo chown root:root /usr/lib/virtualbox
```

Answer (score 3):

https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/16759

in my machine

celticmachine:/var/log# ls -ld /usr

drwxrwxr-x 12 998 998 4096 jún   15 01:46 /usr

celticmachine:/var/log# ls -ld /usr/lib

drwxrwxr-x 172 998 998 28672 jún   26 20:16 /usr/lib

celticmachine:/var/log# chown root:root /usr

celticmachine:/var/log# chown root:root /usr/lib

celticmachine:/var/log# virtualbox

And virtualbox started....

(Debian stretch)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue after upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04. `apt install --reinstall virtualbox` didn't help, here's what worked for me:

```
apt purge virtualbox
apt autoclean
apt autoremove
apt install virtualbox
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is not a virtualbox bug, look at this: [Ticket #16759](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/16759)
It comes when you install something to `/usr` manually, and change the permission or ownership of `/usr`, `/usr/lib`.

So the solution is just to recover them as they used to be:

```
sudo chown root:root /usr
sudo chown root:root /usr/lib
sudo chown root:root /usr/lib/virtualbox
sudo chmod 755 /usr/lib
```

The reference of this answer is here: [cannot run virtualbox on ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/947189/cannot-run-virtualbox-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score 0):

My virtualbox failure occurred with the last update made on 16/Mar/2022

---

usuario-vbox@dell-r730:~$  VBoxHeadless --startvm mysql-vm &
[1] 768281
usuario-vbox@dell-r730:~$ VBoxHeadless: Error -1912 in supR3HardenedMainInitRuntime!
VBoxHeadless: RTR3InitEx failed with rc=-1912

### VBoxHeadless: Tip! It may help to reinstall VirtualBox.
^C
[1]+  Exit 1                  VBoxHeadless --startvm mysql-vm

...
...
They were not turned off from the virtualbox manager. Only from the inside with

## shutdown -h now

I followed the directions above

apt remove virtualbox --purge
apt autoclean
apt autoremove

reboot ...the server so that the latest updated kernel is loaded on March 16 along with the other libraries.

apt install virtualbox

I started the VMs with the commands manually

VBoxHeadless --startvm name1-vm &
VBoxHeadless --startvm name2-vm &
VBoxHeadless --startvm name3-vm &
VBoxHeadless --startvm name4-vm &
VBoxHeadless --startvm name5-vm &

Everything ok was working

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).